# Casting Eval("bitValue") as Bool

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, casting, eval

I have a list view with a HyperLink control within the ItemTemplate. I want to display the link if a returned value is 0 (false), and not display the link if it is 1 (true).

So far I have this:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="lnkReview"
  NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("EnquiryID", @"selectcompany.aspx?enq={0}")%>'
  Text="Review Enquiry"
  Visible='<%# ((bool)Eval("Locked"))==true? false : true %>' />
```

...but this renders an 'Specified cast is not valid' exception.

Examples I've seen elsewhere suugest this should work. I can confirm that the Locked column only returns 0 or 1 (from SQL Server) - surely these should be easily cast from bit/int to bool??

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If Locked is an int you should do this:

```js
<%# ((int)Eval("Locked")) == 1 ? true : false %>
```

But then this should work too, so it returns true when Locked > 0

```js
<%# !((int)Eval("Locked") == 0) %>
```

No matter it is mentioned that Locked contains 0 or 1. It is **still** an **INT** which can for some reason contain values > 1. Therefore i find it good practice to do the check on `== 0` instead of `== 1`. We don't know what `Locked` is used for and in the future the design could change so that `Locked` can contain a value > 1.

Comment: `((int)Eval("Locked")) == 1` is sufficient.

Comment: I could swear I actually tried this. The confusing part is that the field is actually a bit and therefore cannot be > 1, therefore I expected to be able to cast it to bool. Still, treating it as an int works, and that is the important thing! Thanks.

Comment: @leppie - `((int)Eval("Locked"))!=!` - nobody seems to spotted, the logic was reversed... but point taken.. :)

Comment: This solution does not work for me. Why does it seem to work for everyone else? I'm having trouble figuring out if the op started with an int or a bit in the database. I'm starting with a bit.

Comment: This ended up being what my solution looked like: `<%# ((bool)Eval("default")) == false %>`

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19182859/setting-checked-value-for-evalbool

Comment: I still get 'Specified cast is not valid' using this.

Answer (score 11):

SQL is a strange world where bits can have three states 0, 1 and null!
So this means that `Eval("Locked")` is a nullable type bool, not a plain bool
A cast to bool will not be valid if the bit value is null, you have to check that first:

```
(Eval("Locked")!=null && (bool)Eval("Locked")==true)
```

This assumes that null should be mapped to false.

Comment: Are you sure? There should be no problem casting a `bool?` to `bool` if there are no null values (as confirmed by the OP).

Comment: Forgetting the issue of null values, your solution won't work because it won't allow a bit to be cast as a bool for some unknown reason...

Comment: I will add, if you don't have a huge number of rows in the table, you can get rid of nulls in your sql query: IFNULL(`Field`,0) AS `Yes-No` FROM ". As noted somewhere else, tinyint 1 fields shouldn't have nulls, but sometimes stuff happens. And yes, if this is a huge database, I would probably find a better way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

```
Checked='<%# Eval("SEND_EMAIL") == DBNull.Value ? false : Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("SEND_EMAIL")) %>'
```

Comment: This is the only method that helped me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep got also an exception if using null instead of DBNull.Value