# Setting checked value for Eval(bool)

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a property

```
public bool AutoRenew
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

And in the page:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked='<%# Eval("AutoRenew") %>' />
```

but it is always checked, even if the value of the property is `false`.

I tried the following variations:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) %>' />
<input type="checkbox" checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) == true %>' />
<input type="checkbox" checked='<%# (Boolean)Eval("AutoRenew") %>' />
```

but nothing works, it keeps being checked. What should the expression look like?

**EDIT:** Here is the problematic part in the page:

```
...
<asp:ListView ID="MyListView" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table class="ms-listviewtable" style="background-color: White;">
            <tr class="ms-viewheadertr ms-vhltr">
                <th class="ms-vh-icon" scope="col">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                </th>
                <th class="ms-vh2">
                    <div class="ms-vh-div"><a>Training Item</a></div>
                </th>
                <th class="ms-vh2">
                    <div class="ms-vh-div"><a>Training Task Type</a></div>
                </th>
                <th class="ms-vh2">
                    <div class="ms-vh-div"><a>Due Date</a></div>
                </th>
                <th class="ms-vh2">
                    <div class="ms-vh-div"><a>Auto-Renew</a></div>
                </th>
                <th class="ms-vh2">
                    <div class="ms-vh-div"><a>Training Reason</a></div>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr id="itemplaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr class="ms-itmhover">
            <td class="ms-vb-itmcbx ms-vb-firstCell">
                <input type="checkbox" class="s4-itm-cbx" />
            </td>
            <td class="ms-vb-title">
                <div class="ms-vb itx"><a><%# Eval("Title")%></a></div>
            </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="TaskTypeDropDownList" runat="server">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2"><%# Eval("DueDate")%></td>
                <td class="ms-vb2" style="text-align: center;">
                    <input type="checkbox" checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) %>' />
                </td>
                <td class="ms-vb2"><%# Eval("TrainingReason")%></td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
        ...
```

Comment: Took me a bit to remember...  "checked" is one of those attributes that doesn't need a value, but to make it compliant with standards, checked='checked' is used.  And any value would evaluate to "true".

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You are using plain HTML checkbox

to bind data to plain HTML checkbox you must use checked="checked"

If you use ASP.NET Checkbox control then your original code will work smoothly.

There is a difference between plain HTML controls & ASP.NET controls when binding data.

```
 //for asp.net checkbox
 <asp:CheckBox  ID="IdCheckBox" runat="server" Checked="<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) %>"  />

//for plain html checkbox
<input type="checkbox" <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) ? "checked" : "" %> />
```

Comment: It works with `asp:CheckBox`, though I still don't get it why am is it still being checked even if I use @Satpal's code.

Comment: I tried it on sample page,  <input type="checkbox" 
  <%# false ? "checked" : string.Empty %> />, <input type="checkbox" 
  <%# true? "checked" : string.Empty %> />, both conditions works perfectly. Can you post more details

Comment: @Boris : because even <input type="checkbox" checked='' /> will mark checkbox as checked, check Mr47's answer

Comment: tanx for ur answer hny :* jigareto @Nikhil Chavan

Comment: How should it be written if I have CheckBoxList?

Answer (score 3):

Desired output HTML should get you on the way:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked" />
<input type="checkbox" />
```

This means that, to NOT check the checkbox, you should not mention the `checked` attribute in the output at all, not even with a value of false.

Answer (score 2):

Add `checked` attribute if `Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew"))` is `true`

```
<input type="checkbox" 
  <%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("AutoRenew")) ? "checked" : string.Empty %> />
```

Comment: @Boris, great to hear that

Answer (score 1):

you can check anytype value in Grid_RowDataBound Event :

aspx :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridMain" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridMain_RowDataBound">                   
     <Columns>                      
        <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="grid_chkbox" Enabled="false" />
                </ItemTemplate
        </asp:TemplateField>                          
     </Columns>              
</asp:GridView>
```

aspx.cs:

```
protected void GridMain_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
     //find the checkboxes in the template field.
       CheckBox grid_chkbox= (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("grid_chkbox");              

     //find boolean value in current record   
         grid_chkbox.Checked = e.Row.DataItem.boolvalue;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing issue with accepted answer. In case somebody is looking for getting asp checkbox checked property to work,  here is code which worked for me :

```
<td><asp:CheckBox ID="chkHasAbility" runat="server"   Checked='<%#bool.Parse(Eval("HasAbility").ToString())%>' /> </td>
```